# Running two python files at once

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have two python files, one is running a simulation in pygame, and the other takes data and graphs it. I want them to run in two separate windows, but I want the data to be logged as the simulation is running. I have tried multithreading and it doesn't seem to work.

Both functions are just while true loops, and I want them to run in parallel.

```
def main():
    while True:
        clock.tick(simSpeed)

        # quit function
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pendulum.update()
        drawWindow(screen, pendulum)

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
threading.Thread(target=graphData).start()
```

```
def graphData():
    while True:
        x = data.data["x"]
        y = data.data["y"]
        plot1 = plt.figure(1)
        plt.title("poopyhead")
        plt.plot(y, x)

        plot2 = plt.figure(5)
        plt.plot(x, y)

        plot1.clear()
        plot2.clear()

        plt.show()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What error are you getting while mulltithreading?

Comment: When I use multithreading the first function just runs and the second one doesn't. I think this is because there isn't a time when it is waiting for something to happen (like waiting to receive data or something). But my main loop runs and the graph data just doesn't run at all.

Comment: Not sure, but try changing clock.tick(simSpeed) to time.sleep(seconds). For this you would need to import time. It's built-in.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea. My problem with that is that the game would no longer run at a constant speed. clock.tick() keeps it running at a constant fps and makes each while loop take the same amount of time. time.sleep won't do that as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Then you can have two file and run one file from the another.

Comment: @OwenMoogk if you're using a relatively recent version of python, each thread will attempt to release the GIL to let other threads every 15 milliseconds or so. If your second thread doesn't seem to be running, it may be a problem with the GUI backend rather than `Threading` itself.

Comment: I would rather run all in one `while True` without threads. And I would use `tick()` to count time and update plot every 1 second. Or I would use `pygame.time.set_timer()` to generate event every 1 second and use this event to run code which updates plot. It should give better controlo on code. System may run threads in different moments - they don't have to run at the same time - and it can makes big problem.

Comment: @furas yea thats what I ended up doing. Thanks. Not sure how to close the question since I solved it. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not `forum` but `Q&A` portal - you don't close questions (and you don't add `[solved]` to title). You can eventually put your solution as answer below - so maybe it will be useful someone else - and you can mark your answer as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote your answer. This gives you reputation's points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for helping. I ended up just re-rendering the graph in the same window every time the while loop executes. Works well enough for me, and I could just avoid multithreading entirely.